# user defined schema validation without using json schema

Tags: python, json, validation, schema

i would like to have a user defined structure for schema validation. For example, i would like to be able to create different field for a database file and before the data is loaded into the file i would i would like to check for the schema. That can easily be done using json shema and the validate method; however, i do not want to use any package besides standard built in package for python. For example i have

```
"price" : {"type" : "number" and number >45},
"name" : {"type" : "string"}
"age" : {"type" : "number" and number >0}
.................
```

so how can use such schema to validate my input without using json schema

Thank you

Comment: Is there any particular reason for not using [jsonschema](http://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)? It will be much more work to redo that yourself. For much lower quality.

Comment: yes because in the drill, i am not allow to use non built in packages; so if i want to use json schema, i will have to download it; and that is not allow in the drill. There should be way; for now im thinking of using isinstance. for example, for the first field i could have something like: isinstance(number, int) and number>45 .

Answer (score 0):

Best you can do in this case imho is to `eval` validation code after securing it with `ast`

```
# schema_validator.py
import ast


class SchemaSecurityValidationError(Exception):
    pass


class ValidationError(Exception):
    pass


def secure_schema(schema,
                  builitins=__builtins__.__dict__.values(),
                  forbidden_builtins=(file, open, __import__),
                  forbidden_nodes=(ast.Import, ast.ImportFrom)):
    forbidden_builtins_names = tuple(b.__name__ for b in forbidden_builtins)
    for field, field_descriptor in schema.iteritems():
        type_validator = field_descriptor.get('type', None)
        if type_validator is not None:
            if not type_validator in builitins:
                raise SchemaSecurityValidationError(
                    "%s:'type' can only be basic type or builtin" % field)
            if type_validator in forbidden_builtins:
                raise SchemaSecurityValidationError(
                    "%s:'type' cant be of %s type" % (field, type_validator))
        value_validator = field_descriptor.get('validator', None)
        if value_validator is not None:
            tree = ast.parse(value_validator)
            for node in ast.walk(tree):
                if type(node) in forbidden_nodes:
                    raise SchemaSecurityValidationError(
                        "%s:%s is forbidden in validator" % (field, ast.dump(node)))
                if  isinstance(node, ast.Call) \
                        and isinstance(node.func, ast.Name)\
                        and node.func.id in forbidden_builtins_names:
                    raise SchemaSecurityValidationError(
                        "%s:%s is forbidden in validator" % (field, ast.dump(node)))


def validate(record, schema):
    secure_schema(schema)
    for field, field_descriptor in schema.iteritems():
        value = record[field]
        type_validator = field_descriptor.get('type', None)
        if type_validator is not None:
            if not isinstance(value, type_validator):
                raise ValidationError('wrong type blabla')
        value_validator = field_descriptor.get('validator', None)
        if value_validator is not None:
            if not eval(value_validator, {'value': value}):
                raise ValidationError('wrong value blabla')
    return record


#validating with different schemas

schema0 = {'price': {'type': int, 'validator': 'value and value>45'}}
schema1 = {'price': {
    'type': int, 'validator': '__import__("socket") or value and value>45'}}
schema2 = {'price': {
    'type': int, 'validator': 'int("test.py",x=file("test.py")).read() or value and value>45'}}
schema3 = {'price': {
    'type': int, 'validator': 'open("test.py").read() or value and value>45'}}

print validate({'price': 45}, schema0)
print validate({'price': 46}, schema1)
print validate({'price': 46}, schema2)
print validate({'price': 46}, schema3)
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't satisfy your "no package besides standard built in package" constraint, but you might want to consider [Voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous). It's concise, easy to use and we've been very happy with it so far in our project.